# converting directed graph to undirected one using java jung library

Tags: java, graph, jung

I am looking for a way to calculate degree of each node of a directedSparseGraph in a undirected way. unfortunately the `.degree` method give me the sum of indegree and outdegree of each node.
Assume directed graph `G={(A,B),(B,A),(C,D),(D,A)}`. I want to calculate undirected degree for this graph. In this case it would be:A=2, B=1, C=1, D=2.

Regards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figure it out myself. This can be done by using `.getNeighborCount()` method. This method can calculate degree of each node in undirected way.

Answer (score 0):

FYI, the degree of the node is the number of incident edges.  The number of neighbors is the number of nodes which are connected by a single edge.  In the case of your example these should be  identical; you only start getting  discrepancies in the case of parallel or antiparallel edges, or self loops.